# OSMNx: How to return OSM roads using graph_from_point even if its extreme end nodes are not within the distance

Tags: networkx, openstreetmap, osmnx

I want to fetch the road network inside the blue circle. But i am not able to do so as its far end nodes are well beyond 100 meter from the point.
[image]

```
lng,lat=8.89458178871303, 41.657804855447374

road_filter =  '["highway"~"secondary"]'
G=ox.graph_from_point((lat, lng),custom_filter=road_filter,dist=100)
```

Comment: Have you tried the `truncate_by_edge` argument? https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.graph.graph_from_point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
G=ox.graph_from_point((lat, lng),custom_filter=road_filter,dist=100,simplify=False,retain_all=True,truncate_by_edge=True)
```

**simplify=False** and **truncate_by_edge=True** did the trick.
[image]